# How to turn off all CPU on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, energy

I want to confirm that the infiniband protocol clearly not relies on CPU to work. To do so, I have an infiniband program that works and i want to turn off all CPU to see whether it still work or not.

Turn off a single core in ubuntu (12.04) is quite simple.

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

However given 4 cpu I only can turn off 3 of them. How can i turn off all of them without doing tings like suspend the computer ?

Comment: How would the computer work without CPU ?

Comment: Just turn off the computer.

Comment: @michaellaffargue indeed the computer can not work without any CPU I want to confirm that infiniband protocol do not really involve CPU while working. That's why I need to stop them all and test an inifiband program to confirm

Comment: <deleted by the person who wrote it>

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to confirm that the channel adapter interface doesn't use the main processor, I don't think you need to shut down all the cores (which I question if it is even possible).

Disconnect your system from everything, including the IB switch and anything else that might require processing. Use this to obtain a base operating state in terms of system time use, user time, etc.

Reconnect your system to the IB switch and start processing remote requests that should not require any intervention by the main processor. Characterize that operating state.

Then compare them to see if there is anything beyond natural statistical variability. If you do find something, then go back and analyze your system to see if there is some other explanation. Rinse and repeat.

PS I suspect that any usage by the main processor will be obvious. If the variability you detect is small, it probably is due to something other than the adaptor.